# Find number of subarrays (contiguous) with max(subarray) = first or last element of the subarray

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a list of numbers like [2,3,2] I want to find the number of subarrays such that the max(subarray) = first or last element of the subarray. In this example, there are 6 subarrays and those matching the condition are 5.

**My Thoughts:**
I was able to solve this in O(n^2). Maintained an array d[i][j] = max of subarray from i to j and updated it length-wise. with each update, I could increment the counter if the subarray satisfies the condition.

I am unable to come up with something of lower complexity.
One could although lower the Memory Usage if one uses a single dimension d array instead of two. The logic remains same, single dimension works because we only need to reference the previous array.

Comment: Why both [tag:python] and [tag:java]? Please add only the relevant tag

Comment: You might find [this article](https://www.codingninjas.com/studio/library/count-of-subarrays-starting-or-ending-at-an-index-i-such-that-arr-i-is-maximum-in-a-subarray) helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky one, but there is indeed an *O*(*n*) solution: it's possible to make a single pass through the array, with appropriate bookkeeping, to count all such subarrays.

---

To start with, let's pretend that we only want to count subarrays that *start* with their maximum value. We could do that by keeping a stack containing all values that we've encountered that haven't yet been exceeded by later values. For example, if so far we've processed [10, 5, 8, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1], then the stack would contain [10, 8, 4, 4, 3, 1]: the 5 was exceeded by the 8, and the 2 was exceeded by the second 4, but all the other values are still in the stack. If the next value in the array is another 8, then we update the stack (to [10, 8, 8]), and the size of the stack (3) is the number of subarrays that *end* with the new 8 and *start* with their maximum value. (Do you see why?) So we have something like this:

```
public int countSubarraysThatStartAtMax(final int[] array) {
    final List<Integer> stack = new ArrayList<>();
    int result = 0;
    for (final int element : array) {
        // update stack:
        while (stack.size() > 0 && stack.get(stack.size() - 1) < element) {
            stack.remove(stack.size() - 1);
        }
        stack.add(element);
        // use updated stack:
        result += stack.size();
    }
    return result;
}
```

(Note: You may notice that this involves two nested loops, where the outer loop has *n* iterations and each occurrence of the inner loop has potentially up to *n* iterations; so you might think that the total cost is in *Θ*(*n*<sup>2</sup>) time. However, the *total* number of iterations of the inner loop, across *all* occurrences, adds up to at most *n*, because each iteration removes an element from the stack, and we only add a total of *n* elements to the stack. So the total cost is in *O*(*n*) time. The same logic applies to all of the below as well.)

---

Next, let's pretend that we only want to count subarrays that *end* with their maximum value. Of course, we could do this the same way as the above, but going right-to-left instead of left-to-right; but let's imagine that we specifically need to do this with a left-to-right pass. (We'll ultimately need to combine this with the above, into a single more-complicated pass, so they need to go in the same direction.) For this, we keep a stack containing all values *and corresponding indices* that we've encountered that haven't yet been exceeded *or matched* by later values. For example, if so far we've processed [10, 5, 8, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1], then the stack would contain [(10, 0), (8, 2), (4, 5), (3, 6), (1, 7)]: this time we've included the indices, and we've discarded the first occurrence of 4 because there was a later one. If the next value in the array (at index = 8) is another 4, then we pare the stack down to just [(10, 0), (8, 2)], and the number of subarrays that end at that 4 and have max = 4 is 8 − 2. (Do you see why?) Then we add that 4 to the stack. So we have something like this:

```
private static final class StackElement {
    public final int value;
    public final int index;

    public StackElement(final int value, final int index) {
        this.value = value;
        this.index = index;
    }
}

public int countSubarraysThatEndAtMax(final int[] array) {
    final List<StackElement> stack = new ArrayList<>();
    int result = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < array.length; ++index) {
        final int element = array[index];
        // remove obsolete elements from stack:
        while (stack.size() > 0
               && stack.get(stack.size() - 1).value <= element
        ) {
            stack.remove(stack.size() - 1);
        }
        // use updated stack:
        final int indexOfLastGreaterElement =
            stack.size() == 0
                ? -1
                : stack.get(stack.size() - 1).index;
        result += index - indexOfLastGreaterElement;
        // add new element to stack:
        stack.add(new StackElement(element, index));
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

Now, we need to combine the above, while not double-counting subarrays that both start and end with their maximum value. The not–double-counting might seem simple; at first glance, it seems that that we can change `countSubarraysThatStartAtMax` from considering "values that we've encountered that haven't yet been exceeded by later values" to only considering "values that we've encountered that haven't yet been exceeded *or matched* by later values", so that it only counts arrays that start with their maximum value *and don't end with that value*. The problem, though, is that if we remove old values from the stack as soon as they're matched by a later value, then we won't count a subarray like [4, 2, 4, 3]: we'll remove the first 4 as soon as we see the second 4 even though there may be more subarrays that continue past the second 4. And we might think that we can remove the first 4 and then immediately re-add it, but in a case like [4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4], we'd have to remove and re-add multiple 4s at once, such that the algorithm as a whole would require worst-case *Θ*(*n*<sup>2</sup>) time.

The solution to this is to change `countSubarraysThatStartAtMax` so that instead of using the literal size of the stack, it stores a `stackSize` field on stack elements, so that it doesn't need to store multiple copies of the same element:

```
private static final class StackElement {
    public final int value;
    public final int stackSize;

    public StackElement(final int value, final int stackSize) {
        this.value = value;
        this.stackSize = stackSize;
    }
}

public int countSubarraysThatStartButDontEndAtMax(final int[] array) {
    final List<StackElement> stack = new ArrayList<>();
    int result = 0;
    for (final int element : array) {
        // remove obsolete elements from stack:
        StackElement popped = null;
        while (stack.size() > 0
               && stack.get(stack.size() - 1).value <= element
        ) {
            popped = stack.remove(stack.size() - 1);
        }
        // use updated stack:
        final int stackSize =
            stack.size() == 0
                ? 0
                : stack.get(stack.size() - 1).stackSize;
        result += stackSize;
        // add new element to stack:
        if (popped == null || popped.value < element) {
            stack.add(new StackElement(element, stackSize + 1));
        } else {
            stack.add(new StackElement(element, popped.stackSize + 1));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And now it's reasonably straightforward to combine them:

```
private static final class StackElement {
    public final int value;
    public final int lastIndex;
    public final int stackSize;

    public StackElement(
        final int value,
        final int lastIndex,
        final int stackSize
    ) {
        this.value = value;
        this.lastIndex = lastIndex;
        this.stackSize = stackSize;
    }
}

public int countSubarraysThatStartOrEndAtMax(final int[] array) {
    final List<StackElement> stack = new ArrayList<>();
    int result = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < array.length; ++index) {
        final int element = array[index];
        // remove obsolete elements from stack:
        StackElement popped = null;
        while (stack.size() > 0
               && stack.get(stack.size() - 1).value <= element
        ) {
            popped = stack.remove(stack.size() - 1);
        }
        // use updated stack:
        final int stackSize =
            stack.size() == 0
                ? 0
                : stack.get(stack.size() - 1).stackSize;
        result += stackSize;
        final int indexOfLastGreaterElement =
            stack.size() == 0
                ? -1
                : stack.get(stack.size() - 1).lastIndex;
        result += index - indexOfLastGreaterElement;
        // add new element to stack:
        if (popped == null || popped.value < element) {
            stack.add(new StackElement(element, index, stackSize + 1));
        } else {
            stack.add(new StackElement(element, index, popped.stackSize + 1));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

##### Pre-computation

Create two arrays `left` and `right`. For index `i`, `left[i]` would indicate the index of the next greatest element to the left of `arr[i]`. Similarly, `right[i]` would indicate the index of the next greatest element to the right of `arr[i]`. If no such element exists, we can use `inf`.

##### Solution

For each index `i` in range `[0, length of array]`:

- let `l = min(0, left[i]) and r = min(len(arr)-1, right[i])`.
- Any subarray that starts between `[l+1, i]` and ends at `i` will have the last element as its max.
- Any subarray that starts at `i` and ends between `[i+1, r)` will have the first element as its max.
- Calculating the number of subarrays for each case becomes a trivial problem (left as an exercise for the reader).

Comment: So do you just determine a count for each index i separately, and then add up those counts?

Comment: @KellyBundy yes, that's right.

Comment: What are those separate counts for example for input [1,1,1,1]?

Comment: The counts would be `[1,1,1,1]`.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Could you give an example of an array and the left[] and right[] . I am a little confused about the definition of them. Could you please try rephrasing it? Thanks

Comment: But that adds up to only 4 instead of the correct 10.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to find left greater and right greater element for each element A[i] and then traverse from i to len(A) and count number of subarrays that can be formed by including leftGreaterIndex(i)...i and i...rightGreaterIndex(i). The leftGreaterIndex and rightGreaterIndex can be found using monotonic stack. So the count of such subarrays can be calculated as res += (r - i + 1) + (i - l + 1) - 1; // -1 in the end because subarray at l...r will be counted twice.

Time complexity : O(n), where n = len(A)
Space complexity : O(n)

Here is my implementation:

```
public static long count(List<Integer> A) {
    int n = A.size();
    int[] left = leftGreater(A);
    int[] right = rightGreater(A);
    long res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int l = left[i];
        int r = right[i];
        res += (r - i + 1) + (i - l + 1) - 1; // -1 because subarray at l...r will be counted twice
    }
    return res;
}

private static int[] leftGreater(List<Integer> A) {
    int n = A.size();
    int[] res = new int[n];
    Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        while (!st.isEmpty() && A.get(st.peek()) <= A.get(i)) {
            st.pop();
        }
        res[i] = st.isEmpty() ? i : st.peek();
        st.push(i);
    }
    return res;
}

private static int[] rightGreater(List<Integer> A) {
    int n = A.size();
    int[] res = new int[n];
    Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<>();
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        while (!st.isEmpty() && A.get(st.peek()) <= A.get(i)) {
            st.pop();
        }
        res[i] = st.isEmpty() ? i : st.peek();
        st.push(i);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Works with duplicate values**

The crux of the idea is based on pre-computing the array of Next Greater Element(NGE) and Previous Greater than or Equal Element(PGEE). You can compute both these arrays by using a monotonic stack in O(N) time. For a detailed explanation of monotonic stack and its application in finding NGE refer to [this article.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-monotonic-stack-data-structure-and-algorithm-tutorials/) We will focus on the other important aspects of the problem here. Once we have both these arrays computed we will loop through them and compute result by adding all the sub arrays starting or ending at that element, of which the element will be maximum. If there is no greater element to the right we will take nge[i] as len(nums) and if there is no greater or equal element to the left we will take pgee[i] as -1. For each index i the number of sub-arrays ending at i with nums[i] as maximum is i - pgee[i]. The number of sub-arrays starting at i with nums[i] as maximum is nge[i] - i. By adding these two we can arrive at the total number of sub-arrays, there is one caveat though we will be counting the sub-array that starts at i and ends at i twice. Hence we arrive at:

> num sub-arrays for i = i - pgee[i] + nge[i] - i - 1 = nge[i] - pgee[i] - 1

It is necessary to take the greater element for next and greater than or equal element for previous. If you take greater element on both sides it will lead to duplicate counting. Take the example [3,1,3,5], if we take greater element on both sides the sub-array [3,1,3] will get counted twice at its first index and last index. Below is a implementation of the solution in python.

```
from typing import List

class Solution:
def numSubArrays(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
    res = 0
    nge = []
    pgee = []

    stack = []
    for i in range(len(nums) - 1, -1, -1):
        while stack and nums[stack[-1]] <= nums[i]:
            stack.pop()

        if not stack:
            nge.append(len(nums))
        else:
            nge.append(stack[-1])

        stack.append(i)

    nge.reverse()

    stack = []
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        while stack and nums[stack[-1]] < nums[i]:
            stack.pop()

        if not stack:
            pgee.append(-1)
        else:
            pgee.append(stack[-1])

        stack.append(i)

    # print(nge, pgee)
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        res += nge[i] - pgee[i] - 1

    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sol = Solution()
    print(sol.numSubArrays([3,1,3,5]))
    print(sol.numSubArrays([3,4,1,6,5,2]))
    print(sol.numSubArrays([1,1,1,1]))
```

> 10
> 14
> 10

The overall time-complexity is O(N) because we loop through the array 3 times. The space complexity is also O(N).